SF Story - School uses brain implant to punish kids
Story appearing in SF anthology (possibly kids’ sf) from early 2000s or before… Girl visits brother at boarding (reform?) school. Learns that he and other inmates have chips planted in their brains which can administer agonising headaches to punish unacceptable speech ot behaviour. She intends to help but finds that her parents have enrolled her there also and she will presumably get chip of her own implanted.

Presumably the same story as in Science fiction anthology meant for kids with a boarding school mind control chip and a phone that calls the past. Do you remember the other story mentioned in that question?

Vaguely - something about a telephone that got calls from the future, and by predicting someone's death actually caused  it to happen - a sort of "Appointment in Samarkand" situation.
